# Simple median function in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Simply trying to find the median of an array of numbers and I have the following:

```
double median( int* array, int length)
{        
        double median;
        qsort(array, length, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);
        if((length%2) == 0)
        {       
                median = (array[(length/2)] + array[(length/2)-1)])/2;
        }
        else
        {
                median =(array[(length -1)/2]);

        }
        return median;

}
int main ()
{
int array [] = {5, 3, 2, 7, 9};
printf( "%d\n", median (array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])));
return 0;
}
```

My median returns as a crazy huge number. Anyone know why?

Comment: Use %f instead of %d in printf() and see what that gives you.

Comment: Do you know what the median is? ATM, you are getting a wrong answer for `length%2==0` and do a superfluous `-1` in the other case.

Comment: @JohnHascall why `lf` would be more appropriate?

Comment: @ouah to help him remember to use %lf when *scanf'ing a double -- it doesn't really matter in *printf, but I find being consistent works better for beginning C programmers here.   YMMV

Comment: @AlexD It is reasonably common to define the median of a set of even cardinality to be the average of the two middle members.

Comment: @JohnHascall but `lf` is also undefined behavior in c90 with `printf` which not everybody knows / remembers

Comment: Did you read all the links the were provided to you in your other question from today? The median of integers is always an integer, there is no need to change your interface to `double`. And your error has nothing to do with the median function or your implementation. Please try to nail down errors yourself to a minimal example before posting here.

Comment: @ouah - didn't know that, that's what I get for learning C in the 70s :)   -- can you point me to where in C90 that is covered.

Comment: @JohnHascall *(c90, 7.9.6.1 The fprintf function) "[...] If an h, l, or L appears with any other conversion specifier. the behavior is undefined."*

Comment: @ouah -- Thanks, a old dog learned a new trick today!

Comment: @Jens Gustedt Concerning "The median of integers is always an integer".  The better answer is a mathematical answer not a programming one. [Median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) discusses how the median is the _mean_ of the 2 middle values when `n` is even.  It depends on the coding goals.  But even with a _mean_ definition, I agree, no need for `double` math with an `int` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To printf `double` use `%f` instead of `%d` [format specifier](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Comment: Thank you!, much simpler than I thought.